# haskell -- any way to roll your own group of LANGUAGE pragmas?

Tags: haskell, ghc, code-organization

I have a Haskell project that regularly uses a lot of language features, and I want the language extension block for each source file to be the same. Here's a list,

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows,
             BangPatterns,
             DefaultSignatures,
             DeriveDataTypeable,
             DeriveFunctor,
             EmptyDataDecls,
             FlexibleContexts,
             FlexibleInstances,
             FunctionalDependencies,
             GADTs,
             GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,
             MultiParamTypeClasses,
             NamedFieldPuns,
             NoImplicitPrelude,
             NoMonomorphismRestriction,
             OverlappingInstances,
             RankNTypes,
             RebindableSyntax,
             ScopedTypeVariables,
             StandaloneDeriving,
             TemplateHaskell,
             TypeFamilies,
             TypeOperators,
             TypeSynonymInstances,
             UndecidableInstances,
             ViewPatterns #-}
```

Maybe to some it's bad practice, but I consider language extensions to be part of the "Haskell+" that I usually write code in. And, I want that to be the same across modules. For example, the `NoImplicitPrelude` changes the language dramatically, and I want it uniform for all modules.

*Question*: How can I achieve this, without copy-pasting the language block into each file? It gets annoying how I often learn a new language feature, add it to module `A`, then start working on module `B`, and realize I have to go copy the language block from module `A`.

Just FYI the `CPP` pragma with a `#include` does *not* do the trick! Thanks in advance.

Comment: previous related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005382/haskell-ways-to-have-a-clean-import-block-re-exporting-modules-multiple-im

Comment: I would strongly suggest not including `OverlappingInstances` in your list of default extensions.

Comment: @ehird, good point; it is used occasionally though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use cabal as your build system, and list the language extensions you want in the `Extensions` field of the `Library` or `Executable` section of your `project.cabal` file. Then remove the `LANGUAGE` block from your Haskell source files.

See the [Cabal User Guide](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/), including the third paragraph of the introduction.

---

Ghci is where it all falls down. There is talk of adding a `cabal ghci` command, but in the meantime it's a bit icky.

If your project is a library, you can run `ghci -package-conf dist/package.conf.inplace`.

If you want to load unexposed modules in ghci, I'd define a "development mode" flag in your `project.cabal`:

```
Flag development
  Description:          Development mode: expose all modules, enable warnings.
  Default:              False
```

...conditionally expose extra modules in development mode:

```
Library
  Exposed-modules:      My.Module, My.Module.Extra
  if flag(development)
    Exposed-modules:    My.Module.Hidden, My.Module.Secret
    GHC-Options:        -Wall
  -- plus your extensions, etc
```

...and explicitly enable development mode when you run `cabal configure`:

```
$ cabal configure -f development
```

Comment: Looks good. Just one question: how do I use ghci? (preferably on any module in the project -- I don't want to edit the cabal file every time)

Comment: See my edit. Did I correctly understand your point about not wanting to edit the cabal file every time?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The edits are definitely useful, but I think not what I'm looking for. Suppose I'm working on module `A`. Then, without cabal, I can type `ghci A`, and it will attempt to load. I can reload with `:r`, until it works, and then proceed to work on module `B`, by typing `:l B` (or exiting and running `ghci B`).